# Magento Set order of added category attribute

Tags: magento

How can I set the order of an added category attribute following this installation script

```
<?php
$installer = $this;
echo "installing";
$installer->startSetup();
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'title_recipe', array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'text',
'order'      => '999',
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Title Recipe',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));

$this->endSetup();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'title_recipe', array(
'group'         => 'General Information',
'input'         => 'text',
'position'      => 999,
'type'          => 'text',
'label'         => 'Title Recipe',
'backend'       => '',
'visible'       => true,
'required'      => false,
'visible_on_front' => true,
'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
));
```